# How can I control an image being displayed in the html selector in css?

Tags: html, css, background-image

CODE:

```
html {
    background: url("/_images/back.png") no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Using this I am able to display the image perfectly but the entire image doesn't get displayed from the top.  If this were in a div i could display it properly and control via margin-top but with html I am limited unless there is something else.

How can I show the entire image? is there something similar to margin-top?

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful.

Comment: What if you try `background: url("/_images/back.png") no-repeat top left fixed; ` ??

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for `background-size:contain` but that would be too easy, wouldn't it?

Comment: @starbucks I posted it as a question with a better explanation. If it helped and you accept I'll appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) property is a *shorthand* for some background properties of CSS. One of them is the [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) which can hold positions like `top`, `center`, `bottom`, or `left` and `right` or values in `%`, `px`, `em`, `cm` and so on...

You don't need to use divs for that purpose.

So in your case, you may try `background: url("/_images/back.png") no-repeat top left fixed;`.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the **body** tag ? also you can try the [yahoo css reset](http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/base/base-min.css)